# JAXB annotation need to be known to bind xml with my class

Tags: binding, jaxb

I have the following classes

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "ExecutionRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExecutionRequest {

    @XmlElement(name="Command")
    private String command;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="ExecutionParameters")
    @XmlElement(name="ExecutionParameter")
    private ArrayList<ExecutionParameter> ExecutionParameters;

}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExecutionParameter {

    @XmlElement(name = "Key")
    private String key;

    @XmlElement(name = "Value")
    private String value;

}
```

and when I marshall the ExecutionRequest object, I get the following XML -

```xml
<ExecutionRequest>
  <Command>RetrieveHeader</Command>
  <ExecutionParameters>
    <ExecutionParameter>
      <Key>tid</Key>
      <Value>ASTLGA-ALTE010220101</Value>
    </ExecutionParameter>
    <ExecutionParameter>
      <Key>ctag</Key>
      <Value>dq</Value>
    </ExecutionParameter>
  </ExecutionParameters>
</ExecutionRequest>
```

It is working fine as per JAXB binding. 
But I want the XML to have all key value collection within one ExecutionParameter like -

```xml
<ExecutionRequest>
  <Command>RetrieveHeader</Command>
  <ExecutionParameters>
    <ExecutionParameter>
      <Key>tid</Key>
      <Value>ASTLGA-ALTE010220101</Value>
      <Key>ctag</Key>
      <Value>dq</Value>
    </ExecutionParameter>
  </ExecutionParameters>
</ExecutionRequest>
```

Is there any way to obtain xml like this by changing annotation.
Let me know in case of clarifications.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't metadata for that.  You could get a compact XML representation (that is easily parseable) by mapping `key` and `value` with `@XmlAttribute`.

```xml
<ExecutionParameters>
     <ExecutionParameter Key="a" Value="b"/>
     <ExecutionParameter Key="c" Value="d"/>
</ExecutionParameters>
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you have to support this XML format, then you could use JAXB with XSLT to get the desired result:

```java
    // Create Transformer
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(
            "src/example/stylesheet.xsl");
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer(xslt);

    // Source
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ExecutionRequest.class);
    JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, request);

    // Result
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    // Transform
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/using-jaxb-with-xslt-to-produce-html.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise, you mean to change xml element to xml attribute so that I could have list of execution parameters with key and value attributes.Am I right?  But this execution request object has to be marshalled and send xml to other system in the format I mentioned earlier. Is there any other way to achieve it?  Thanks!

Comment: @Hari - Are you interacting with the JAXB `Marshaller` directly or is this done automatically for you via JAX-WS or JAX-RS?  Do you need to handle unmarshalling as well?

Comment: Yes... I am interacting with JAXB Marshaller directly. I need to unmarshall but not ExecutionRequest, it is ExecutionResponse which I will receive from third party system.

Comment: @Hari - Does it have the same type of requirement?

Comment: No, both ExecutionRequest and ExecutionResponse objects are different and they both have completely different xml structure and elements.

Comment: I tried JAXB with XSLT and I got the following response after marshalling - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ExecutionRequest> 
    <Command>RetrieveHeader</Command>  </ExecutionRequest>   where I didnt get ExecutionParameter in request.

Comment: This is the style sheet I used - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> <xsl:template match="/"> <ExecutionRequest> <Command>RetrieveHeader</Command> <xsl:for-each select="executionRequest/executionParameter"> <ExecutionParameters> <ExecutionParameter> <key> <xsl:value-of select="key" /> </key> <value> <xsl:value-of select="value" /> </value> </ExecutionParameter></ExecutionParameters> </xsl:for-each> </ExecutionRequest> </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Execution Request object - ExecutionRequest executionRequest = new ExecutionRequest();
 executionRequest.setCommand("RetrieveHeader");

 ArrayList<ExecutionParameter> ExecutionParameters = new ArrayList<ExecutionParameter>(2);
        ExecutionParameters.add(new ExecutionParameter("tid", "ASTLGA-ALTE010220101"));
        ExecutionParameters.add(new ExecutionParameter("ctag", "dq"));
        executionRequest.setParameters(ExecutionParameters);
Blaise, If you have any ideas, let me know... Thanks!